# PHP Writing Newline from Form Submission

Tags: php, forms, newline

I read every results I had with this kind of issue but it seems I couldn't fix it. I just want my .txt file to create a new line and disable overwriting the said file if someone submitted a new entry.

This is the form:

```
<form action="shots.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" name="caption" maxlength="180" placeholder="Enter caption here..."><br>
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Now">
</form>
```

This is the php code:

```
<?php
$f = fopen("textfile.txt", "w");
fwrite($f, $_POST["caption"]); 
fclose($f);
$f = fopen("textfile.txt", "r");
echo fgets($f); 
fclose($f);

if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$allowed_type = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png");
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if($image_size > 800000) {
  echo "<br><div style='color: #ff4040'>File size too big.</div>";
  exit();   
}

if(!in_array($image_type, $allowed_type)) {
  echo "<br><div style='color: #ff4040'>Only jpg, gif, and png files are allowed.</div>";
  exit();   
}

if($image_name==''){
echo "<br><div style='color: #ff4040'>Please select an image first!</div>";
exit(); 
}

else
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name,"larawan/$image_name");
echo "<br><div style='color: green'>Upload complete! A Game Master will now review your screenshot.</div><br>";
echo "<img style='width: 50%; height: auto' src='larawan/$image_name'>";
}

?>
```

Ciao!

Comment: i think youre looking for `/n`

Comment: I am totally lost mate. Can you re-post a code for me please.

Comment: You should also append (`a`) instead of writing (`w`) to the file, if you don't want it to be overwritten

Comment: @DamienPirsy I appended it to "a" and yes the text now never overwritten. Now my problem is the .txt file looks like this:
`Submit1Submit2Submit3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
$f = fopen("textfile.txt", "w");
fwrite($f, $_POST["caption"]); 
fclose($f);
```

with:

```
file_put_contents("textfile.txt", $_POST["caption"] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

This adds to the end of the file instead of overwriting it, and puts a newline after each line.

To include the filename that the user submitted:

```
file_put_contents("textfile.txt", $_POST["caption"] . " - " . $_FILES['image']['name'] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

You should move this code into the `if` block, so it's only done after testing that here was a form uploaded.

Comment: Furthermore, is there a way I could add to the text file the file name that user submitted from the form? Example:
`CaptionSubmitted101 - wallpaperentry.jpeg`

Comment: Thank you sir. I already move it in the `if` block and everything is ok now. Thank you very much sir!